# SAML2 authentication : xmlsec1 error xmlSecOpenSSLEvpSignatureVerify data do not match (Synapse/SAML2)

Tags: python, certificate, saml-2.0, matrix-synapse, xmlsec1

I've been struggling for several days to get SAML2 authentication to work between Matrix (Synapse) and Shibboleth.

The problem seems to be at the `xmlsec1` level which is called by `pysaml2`, when the IDP response is received.

Here's the error I get :

```
2023-11-22 14:30:26,742 - synapse.handlers.saml - 120 - INFO - GET-0 - Initiating a new SAML session: id-6i5N7jiDt5GSBPIPJ
2023-11-22 14:30:26,742 - synapse.rest.client.login - 662 - INFO - GET-0 - Redirecting to https://[MY-IDP]/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?SAMLRequest=nZLPTuMwEMZfxfKlF1K3KX8kq61UqBaKoERN2QOrFTLJlA5KJsEzqcoj8Ry8GE5hF%2FbSwx5n%2FH3275vxkLhnJ42saQHPDbCobVkQ29Ae6caTrRxjKF0JbCWz6eT6ysbdnq19JVVWFfqvob%2Ff4JjBC1ak1Ww60phHx3g0P3nCqRydp6fJLLnU6id4DpKRDo6gY25gRiyOJLR68SDq96M4XvYHdtCz8fGdVtPAjORk51qL1GyNwbw%2B7DaEmQPqrnxbmwC8wgJMCxSbBeToIROTpjdaJZ9hTpFypMf9QR4%2BRGwvlsskSm7SpVaTP%2BHOKuKmBJ%2BC32AGt4urL6rSicdtxGt8%2BA53zy%2FkagaTFQgkhl1ZxMa1O7n3wHW4EXaIG8zBzwPPSP%2FqXAOzewSPoPBjQo7eXkHdEm7aIcrbq8pBnYVH1LzypQvQ0DlQnZXv%2FNbjYdiX3c3Xqx%2FtsewP3XbCylY7qQ2YKC96%2FF%2FJShCXO3Hd8HGG5otj3Bb%2FfsbxOw%3D%3D&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2F[MY-MATRIX]%2Fclient%2F
2023-11-22 14:30:26,742 - synapse.access.http.8008 - 465 - INFO - GET-0 - (null) - 8008 - {None} Processed request: 0.001sec/-0.000sec (0.000sec, 0.000sec) (0.000sec/0.000sec/0) 0B 302 "GET /_matrix/client/v3/login/sso/redirect/saml?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2F[MY-MATRIX]%2Fclient%2F&org.matrix.msc3824.action=login HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" [0 dbevts]
2023-11-22 14:30:26,941 - saml2.sigver - 850 - ERROR - POST-1 - returncode=1
error=func=xmlSecOpenSSLEvpSignatureVerify:file=evp_signatures.c:line=453:obj=rsa-sha256:subj=unknown:error=18:data do not match:details=EVP_VerifyFinal: signature verification failed
FAIL
SignedInfo References (ok/all): 1/1
Manifests References (ok/all): 0/0
Error: failed to verify file "/tmp/tmprwgoyufy.xml"

output=
2023-11-22 14:30:26,941 - saml2.sigver - 1494 - ERROR - POST-1 - check_sig: ['/usr/bin/xmlsec1', '--verify', '--enabled-reference-uris', 'empty,same-doc', '--enabled-key-data', 'raw-x509-cert', '--pubkey-cert-pem', '/tmp/tmpnyhx53_2.pem', '--id-attr:ID', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol:Response', '--node-id', '_61a09c8608cf8d8dba609de8f42fa554', '--output', '/tmp/tmpp1jl60pc.xml', '/tmp/tmprwgoyufy.xml']
2023-11-22 14:30:26,941 - saml2.entity - 1454 - ERROR - POST-1 - Signature Error: Failed to verify signature
2023-11-22 14:30:26,941 - saml2.client_base - 800 - ERROR - POST-1 - XML parse error: Failed to verify signature
2023-11-22 14:30:26,942 - synapse.access.http.8008 - 465 - INFO - POST-1 - (null) - 8008 - {None} Processed request: 0.031sec/-0.000sec (0.005sec, 0.002sec) (0.000sec/0.000sec/0) 12367B 400 "POST /_synapse/client/saml2/authn_response HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" [0 dbevts]
```

And here's how the certificates were generated (I'm not very comfortable with certificates) :

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout /etc/matrix-synapse/saml-key.pem -out /etc/matrix-synapse/saml-cert.pem -nodes -days 9999 -subj "/CN=[MY-MATRIX]"
```

And all librairies seems installed on my server :

```
libxmlsec1-openssl/stable,now 1.2.37-2 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libxmlsec1/stable,now 1.2.37-2 amd64  [installé, automatique]
python3-xmlsec/stable,now 1.3.13-1+b1 amd64  [installé]
xmlsec1/stable,now 1.2.37-2 amd64  [installé]
```

Here is the SAML2 part in the homeserver.yaml :

```
saml2_config:
  sp_config:
    metadata:
      local: ["/etc/matrix-synapse/shib-metadata.xml"]
    key_file: /etc/matrix-synapse/saml-key.pem
    cert_file: /etc/matrix-synapse/saml-cert.pem
    encryption_keypairs:
      - key_file: /etc/matrix-synapse/saml-key.pem
        cert_file: /etc/matrix-synapse/saml-cert.pem
  user_mapping_provider:
    config:
      mxid_source_attribute: uid
```

And here is the shib-metadata.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EntityDescriptor  xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:shibmd="urn:mace:shibboleth:metadata:1.0" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:mdui="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:metadata:ui"  entityID="https://[MY-IDP]/idp/shibboleth">
    <IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0">
        <Extensions>
            <shibmd:Scope regexp="false">[MY-MATRIX]</shibmd:Scope>
        </Extensions>
        <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>[CERTIFICATE]</ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>[CERTIFICATE]</ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://[MY-IDP]:8443/idp/profile/SAML2/SOAP/ArtifactResolution" index="1"/>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:nameIdentifier</NameIDFormat>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:profiles:AuthnRequest" Location="https://[MY-IDP]/idp/profile/Shibboleth/SSO"/>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://[MY-IDP]/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO"/>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" Location="https://[MY-IDP]/idp/profile/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign/SSO"/>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://[MY-IDP]/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO"/>
    </IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

In the codes above :

- `[MY-MATRIX]` corresponds to the url of my Matrix server
- `[MY-IDP]` is the url of my identity provider.

**Thanks for any hint !**

Comment: For anyone who happens to come across it here, all our tests have come to nothing. We believe that pysaml2 via Matrix is not compatible with a Shibboleth SP for federation. A solution could be SATOSA, but this has not been tested: https://github.com/IdentityPython/SATOSA